# Update Custom Object that is uses inlineeditsupport

Tags: visualforce

I creating a list that uses unlineeditsupport. I am having trouble updating when I press the save button.

```
<apex:page standardController="Students__c" extensions="StudentCourseList">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Student Schedule" id="student_schedule">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CourseDetails}" var="st">
                /*
                    BLAH BLAH CODE 
                */
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!st.Grade__c}">
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" resetfunction="callonCancelAction" showonedit="saveAccid, cancelAccId"></apex:inlineEditSupport>
                    </apex:outputfield>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageblockbuttons>
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!saveGrade}" id="SaveAccid" value="Save"></apex:commandbutton>
                    <apex:commandbutton id="cancelAccId" onclick="callonCancelAction()" value="Cancel"></apex:commandbutton>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the function "saveGrade":

```
public class StudentCourseList {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    public string studentcourse_id {get;set;}
    public string newGrade {get;set;}
    private Students__c s;
    public StudentCourseList(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.controller = controller;
    this.s = (Students__c)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<StudentCourseDtlAssc__c> CourseDetails;
    public List<StudentCourseDtlAssc__c> getCourseDetails(){
        Id sId = s.Id;
        List<StudentCourseDtlAssc__c> courses = Database.query(
        'SELECT StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.FKCourse__r.Name,'+
        'StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Id, ' +
        'StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.DOW_Abbr__c,' +
        'StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.Professor__c,' + 
        'StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.FKRoom__r.Name,' +
        'StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Grade__c,' +
        'StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.StartDate__c FROM StudentCourseDtlAssc__c ' +
        'WHERE StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Student__r.Id=:sId');
        return courses;
    }

    public PageReference deleteCourse() {
        List<StudentCourseDtlAssc__c> deleteObj = [SELECT Id FROM StudentCourseDtlAssc__c WHERE StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Id =:studentcourse_id];
        delete deleteObj;
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference saveGrade() {

        List<StudentCourseDtlAssc__c> updateObj = [SELECT Id FROM StudentCourseDtlAssc__c WHERE StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Id =:studentcourse_id LIMIT 1];
        //updateObj.Grade__c = newGrade;
        upsert updateObj;
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I press 'Save' nothing happens. The field does not save.

Comment: 1. You do not have a rerender on your command button. @. You are not showing any page messages so you will not know if there are any errors. 3. Your update DOES NOTHING, all you are doing is a query and update go the records in the query so there are no changes...

Comment: how would you suggest i fix it?

Comment: That all depends on the rest of your cod and what you are trying to do. For starters, you should be updating the records from courseDetails since that is what you are editing. Unfortunately, if you do not understand that `Account a = [Select ID From Account LIMIT 1]; update a` does not actually update any fields in the record (and if you do know that then why would you write your code that way) then you should start at https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead and start learning...

Comment: isn't the point of stack exchange is to get help and explain specific issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `CourseDetails` to be kept in a field of your Controller extension (it may already be). When the command button is clicked, the modifications will be automatically applied to the CourseDetails list so your save method can just `upsert CourseDetails`.

As Eric suggests, add an `apex:pageMessages` to your page too as otherwise validation errors that might block the save will be hidden.

**PS**

It is only necessary to specify a SOQL query via a string (dynamic SOQL) when you want to vary the query at run-time beyond what can be done in the available where clauses. If the query can be done in static SOQL you can avoid the noise of the string delimeters and also get the content of the query checked at compile time.

A common way to get data into a field and also available to the page is to use this [properties syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) and [lazy load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) the data:

```
public List<StudentCourseDtlAssc__c> courseDetails {
    get {
        if (courseDetails == null) {
            courseDetails = [
                    SELECT
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.FKCourse__r.Name,
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Id,
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.DOW_Abbr__c,
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.Professor__c,
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.FKRoom__r.Name,
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Grade__c,
                            StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Course_Detail__r.StartDate__c
                    FROM StudentCourseDtlAssc__c
                    WHERE StudentCourseDtlAssc__c.Student__r.Id = :s.Id
                    ];
        }
        return courseDetails
    }
    set;
}
```

This should allow you to inline edit the data and then save it using:

```
public PageReference saveGrade() {
    upsert courseDetails;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by ''CourseDetails to be kept in a field of your Controller extension'? I added my full code

Comment: @PeterSun See the PS. In that version `courseDetail`s is a field of the controller and Visualforce preserves such fields and updates them automatically. The tutorials will take you through this more clearly than I can.

Comment: i obviously do not fully understand VF (just started last week for a class)... i changed my code to reflect your suggestions.. now the list is not loading.. it is initializing but the blockTable is not loading the data...

Comment: @PeterSun Probably time then to add System.debug calls and see what is going on.

Comment: i was using that system debug calls... they are very useful.. i figured out what i did wrong.. i mistyped the code